Error when using Gulp to build a Helix based solution using VS 2019
While running gulp task, I am getting the below error
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\Web\Deploy\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Deploy.FileSystem.targets(96,5): error : Copying file obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\bin\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll to E:\inetpub\wwwroot\local.dev.local\bin\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll failed. 
The process cannot access the file 'E:\inetpub\wwwroot\local.dev.local\bin\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll' because it is being used by another process. [E:\scprojects\Website\src\Foundation\local\Log4Net\code\Sitecore.Foundation.Log4Net.csproj]

I am using VS 2019, also this error is not specific to any dll ,if I run the gulp task again I get same issue with another dll.
Any help how can I fix it ?
